# Getting the Shipping Address from Paypal NVP Request

Tags: php, paypal, nvp

I want to retrieve the confirmed shipping address paypal has when a user pays through NVP.

Is there a way to do this? or do I always have to ask for their address ahead of time when processing the payment through the express-checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with the Express Checkout API..??  If so, the GetExpressCheckoutDetails request is what would return the shipping address for the buyer.

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails Current link; paypal seems to change their documentation frequently..

Comment: Looks like everything for address is deprecated there; or am I missing something from it?

Comment: The deprecated parameters are the basic ones.  For example, SHIPTONAME is no longer used.  Instead, it's PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTONAME.  This is because you can do parallel payments with Express Checkout now, so you could have multiple payments on a single transaction with different addresses for each.  So the n will become 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. depending on how many payments/addresses were on the order.

Comment: herp derp; sorry about that reading it the first time I thought the second line was just describing what the top line was.  Got it all now :)  Thank you!!